# why cant I change button title in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to ios, and trying to change a simple button text from implementation side in an action.
I have tried two of these: while one of them works, the other one doesnt !

```
self.Btn_Analyse.titleLabel.text = @"Stop Anlaysing";  // didnt work
```

And...

```
[self.Btn_Analyse setTitle:@"Deneme" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //worked
```

why doesnt the first one work?
PS: I have connected the button as IBOutlet

Comment: Is `Btn_Analyse` connected properly in IB?

Comment: what do you mean by properly? I have an IBOutlet in interface and I have drag btn_Analyse outlet in fileowner to the button in xib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you telling us what worked?

If it worked then there isn't a problem.

Anyway, the reason the first one didn't work is because a button is not just a label. It has various states and each state can have different properties.

You set the image for the state. You set the title for the state. etc...

Then with different states you can have different properties.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. I got the difference now. so I cannot change it by changing its text only. another question, in general should I seek a method to change something in a view, or my first approach can work for some other controls?  by the way I added the worked one in order to take attention to the difference.

Comment: It depends on the control. For instance for a `UILabel` you can do `label.text = @"Blah";` and for `UISlider` you can do `slider.value = 0.5;` or `[slider setValue:0.5 animated:YES];` (the latter will animate the change.

Comment: oh I see it better now. thanks a lot Fogmeister, Regards

Answer (score 4):

UIButton sets the title on its own, so if you directly change the text in label, button changes it back.
That's because button can have different titles for different states (label can't do that), and sets the appropriate one automatcally.

Comment: I am sorry but I couldnt understand what you mean by "if you directly change the text in label, button changes it back."

Comment: Well, basically, UIButton consists of couple of views - button itself, and added on it UILabel and UIImageView (for icon). If you access button.titleLabel you get direct access that uilabel. So in theory you can set its text like you do in other UILabels. I used directly, because you are accessing the internal label and trying to change its properties directly, instead of doing it by setting it in button, that owns the label.